# HTML to Textile Java library

Tags: java, html, textile

I need to parse a String from HTML to [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29).

I've been looking at Textile4J, Textile-J, JTextile, PLextile.
But so far, none of them provide the functionality I'm looking for.
They do provide the reverse functionality (Textile to HTML).

Worst case scenario, I can use another programming language, but I have not really looked into that.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? You have HTML and you need to convert it to String? What is 'HTML' you have? Example in pseudocode?

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov I need to convert it from an HTML String e.g. "...<h4>One column:</h4><table border=\"1\">" to [textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) e.g. "hn. One column:
|_. a|_. table|_. header|
|a|table|row|
|a|table|row|"

Comment: It seems you want convert HTML to some specific format? Or just remove all tags from html?

Comment: Indeed, I wish to convert HTML to the specific "Textile" format. (see link in question)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Read Textile as Textfile and couldn't understand what you want :)

Comment: I know this thread is a little outdated, but have you come to any conclusion/discovery worth an update of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I don't believe the functionality I want is available in any java Textile library.
I'll try and update this post if and when that changes.

Based on the libraries mentioned above, I have created my own (limited) functionality.

There are also several solutions available in python / ruby.